# support unknown number of levels of hierarchy in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, tree

I'm using jqGrid and I need to display a tree grid with unknown number of levels(subgrids).

There is an example of hierarchical grid in jqGrid demonstrations but it's good only if you know the number of levels in advance, in this case it's supporting 2 levels only.

Here is the code:[jqGrid subgrid example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Any idea how to support unknown number of tree nodes ahead? i.e., sometimes it's may be 2 levels, sometimes 1(only root) level, sometimes 4 levels and so on...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this.

```
$("#TopLevelGrid").jqGrid({
    ...        
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: expandScript,
    ...
});
// Append information about the level to the TopLevelGrid html-table element
$("#TopLevelGrid").data("currentLevelId", 1);
$("#TopLevelGrid").addClass("MyGrid");      // Ensure that html-table has class MyGrid

function expandScript(parentDivId, parentRowId)
{
        ...
        var parentTable = $("#" + parentDivId").closest("table.MyGrid");
        var parentLevelId = $(parentTable).data("currentLevelId");

        var currentLevelId = parentLevelId + 1;                     // calculate the ID of the current level
        var currentLevelHasChildLevel = true;                       // calculate if the current level has a childLevel
        // Append a table-element which will hold the new grid;     // the same as the jqGrid-subgrid example
        $('#' + parentDivId).append('<table class=\"MyGrid\" id=\"ChildGrid_' + currentLevelId + '\"></table><div id=\"Pager_ChildGrid_' + currentLevelId + '\"></div><br />');
        $('#ChildGrid_' + currentLevelId ').jqGrid({
            ...
            subGrid: currentLevelHasChildLevel,
            subGridRowExpanded: expandScript,                       // recursive call to expandScript function
            ...
        });
        // Save the currentLevelId as custom-data element bound to the html-table element which will also hold the child-grid
        $("#ChildGrid_" + currentLevelId).data("currentlevelid", currentLevelId);
        ...
}
```